# Symfony2 CMF: Using Doctrine ORM instead of PHPCR ODM

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony-cmf

I'm working in a project in `Symfony2` and i want to use `Symfony CMF` with `Doctrine ORM`.

In my config.yml:

```
knp_menu:
    twig: true

cmf_routing:
    dynamic:
        persistence:
            orm:
                enabled: true
                manager_name: ~
```

I'm getting this error:

```
[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ParameterNotFoundException]  
You have requested a non-existent parameter "None of the managerParameters    
resulted in a valid name".
```

Im triying to use `Doctrine ORM` instead of `PHPCR ODM`

Someone knows what can i do?

Thanks!

Comment: Provide some more code. Is symfony not returning the exact line where this error is occurring?

Comment: Is just an configuration error, before the installation of Symfony2 CMF, if clear cache or if try to access to any routes...

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but did you configure doctrine orm in general? what happens if you remove the `manager_name: ~` line?

Comment: If i remove the `manager_name`, he will give the exact same error... If i give an incorrect name he will give this error:       "The service definition "doctrine.orm.test_metadata_driver" does not     exist." I put 'test' in the manager_name